# Majority of threads in WAIT state

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm monitoring a system that has been done in Java and at certain times during the day the vast majority of Threads enter WAIT state and are waiting for about 50 seconds on average, and sometimes the interval between breaks is 5 minutes. The result is that all user requests are waiting.

My question is how to know which thread put all others to wait? I've used some software that analyze Thread Dump, but could not find the cause yet.

I'm suspecting it is the GC that the clear memory put everything on pause until finished.

[image]

In this image, the next 10:16 AM the vast majority entered the WAIT state, had to cut the photo because it has much more Threads and all in the same state.

Comment: Waiting is normal for a thread.  50 seconds for a user request is probably not.  You need to profile individual thread performance, find *where* the threads are waiting in the code, then determine what you can do about it.

Comment: That is my question, how to make the profile of each thread?

Comment: @adelmo00: From what I can tell from the screenshot these are http handlers from the webserver's thread pool that are blocked. They can be blocked because the code that handles the request may be deadlocked due to coding error or because there is a problem with a library being used. Can't you check the logs to see what's happening when the deadlocks happen? You won't be able to see something from the tools if e.g. some thread is misbehaving and doesn't call `notify`

Comment: Threads do not enter a sleep state during gc pause.  Gc pause causes no change to thread state.

Comment: @JimN even with the UseParallelGC argument on a single-core Gargabe the collector not paralyzes the threads?

Comment: At times, the garbage collector will suspend the entire vm to perform its work.  However it does not change the state of individual threads.